# Sprintf Matlab with Apostrophe

Tags: matlab

I have a string listed below with apostrophe.

```
stringVar = '''L''hopital''s rule'''
```

when I do sprintf i.e. sprintf(stringVar) it prints this 'L'hopital's rule'.

Now, what I would like to do is do an sprintf so that when I print it it will display as

'L''hopital''s rule'

Now I know I can easily do this `'''L''''hopital''''s rule'''` but would prefer to do it programatically. What's the best/correct way of approaching this problem. Note: I will need to handle many of these e.g. '''L''Environment'''.

Comment: So: what is the criterion to determine which quote signs you need to duplicate? All except for the first and last? Only those that are between words?

Comment: Only the ones that are in between letters.

Comment: @LuisMendo Looks like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ind = regexp(stringVar, '\w''\w') + 1; %// detect quotes between word characters
stringVarRep = stringVar(sort([1:numel(stringVar) ind])); %// repeat those quotes
```